# simple checkout in git?

Tags: git, github

I am experimenting with branching on git and running into nightmare after nightmare.  Anyway, the current issue is that I wanted to merge the master into the branch.  I tried "git rebase" because some site recommended that, and it did a number of destructive things but definitely did NOT merge my trunk into the branch.  It actually blew up everything quite horribly and created all kinds of complicated merge errors and I cannot figure out how to simply revert my code to where it was before.

My question is twofold:

1) How do I make git completely revert to the point just before the git rebase?  Everything I try gives me all kinds of headaches about merge errors.  I don't want to merge anything.  I just want to take a specific revision exactly as it was and make that the HEAD.

2) Once I get the mess cleaned up, how do I merge a trunk into a branch?  For what it's worth, the merge should not be all that complicated in terms of conflicts.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "trunk". There are only branches. What exactly are you trying to refer to when you say "trunk"?

Comment: @meagar - Are you seriously asking the question or just making point of how git is different or atleast the convention is different?

Comment: @manojlds I am seriously asking, as a means to gain some insight into OP's misconceptions so I can help them understand how it actually works.

Comment: I am seriously asking the question.  I have a codebase that is essentially locked until I figure out the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try `git reset --hard` to throw out the changes (including conflicts) in the working directory and reset your branch to its pre-merge-attempt state.
2. From the branch you want to *merge into*, use `git merge <other branch>`. If there are conflicts, resolve them by opening the files and merging the lines between the `<<<<<` and `>>>>>` conflict markers, then `git add <merged file>`. When you have manually resolved all the conflicts, `git commit` to finish the merge.

Comment: I did: "git reset --hard <SHA>" with the SHA hash of the revision I want.  I got "HEAD is now at fd01dc6".   Now when I do "git status" I get "Your branch is behind 'origin/PersonalSite' by 10 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.".  The problem of course is I can't push because I'm not fast forwarded.  How do I make the remote branch just forget everything and let me push to remote from this new spot?

Comment: `git push -f` will push regardless of the state of the remote branch.

Comment: That did it, with the added benefit of git just totally forgetting the 10 merge hell commits I had made.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the middle of a rebase, and you find that you can't fix the conflicts that arise, you can always abort the rebase with:

```
git rebase --abort
```

... which will restore your branch to its state before you started the rebase.